# How would I filter out sub documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

1) How can I grab all songs with more than 50 likes? The result set should return an array of songs instead of the whole document.

2) How can I return the results of a specific song id instead of the whole document?

So far I've come across this concept of [virtual collections](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) for embedded objects. However, it hasn't been implemented since. Although, on the same link, someone suggests using the aggregation framework for such a thing. Is this a viable solution?

I have the following document structure:

```
document = {
  'date' => Time.now.utc.strftime('%Y%m%d'),
  'songs' => {
    '1' => {
      'views' => {
        'non_uniques' => 2000,
        'uniques' => 203
      },
      'countries' => {
        'us' => 123,
        'uk' => 11
      },
      'likes' => 123,
      'comments' => 123
    },
    '2' => {
      'views' => {
        'non_uniques' => 2000,
        'uniques' => 203
      },
      'countries' => {
        'us' => 123,
        'uk' => 11
      },
      'likes' => 123,
      'comments' => 123
    }
  },
  'sign_ins' => {
    'non_uniques' => 2000,
    'uniques' => 203
  }
}
```

**Expected output (as requested)**

For question 1), somewhere within the lines of:

`['1' => {
          'views' => {
            'non_uniques' => 2000,
            'uniques' => 203
          },
          'countries' => {
            'us' => 123,
            'uk' => 11
          },
          'likes' => 123,
          'comments' => 123
        },
        '2' => {
          'views' => {
            'non_uniques' => 2000,
            'uniques' => 203
          },
          'countries' => {
            'us' => 123,
            'uk' => 11
          },
          'likes' => 123,
          'comments' => 123
        }]`

For 2):

`'1' => {
      'views' => {
        'non_uniques' => 2000,
        'uniques' => 203
      },
      'countries' => {
        'us' => 123,
        'uk' => 11
      },
      'likes' => 123,
      'comments' => 123
    }`

Comment: show us the expected output,how should it look likes? which will help to give you quick answers.

Comment: this would be easy to do with Redis - dump parts of the documents into a Redis sorted set structure, and use: http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore - ofcourse, this would require you to have a running Redis instance...

Comment: I have a Redis instance. However, parsing through a large Mongo document, in Ruby, to to dump parts of it into a sorted Redis set, will be taxing on the application side. I'm hoping there is a way to do this directly via Mongodb (db side) instead.

Comment: I don't see why it would be preferable to do it in Ruby - I think it's correct to make the DB do the work and only return the songs you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation framework like this:

```
db.songs.aggregate({$unwind:"$songs"},{$match:{"songs.likes":{$gt:50}}})
```

Now you can add other stages like {$group} if you want things back in one doc, or $project to change the field names, etc.

Comment: {$group} is how you can merge all the songs back into same documents they were in before.  {$project} is how you can rename fields.  In case that's not clear.

Comment: Aggregation would work, except `$unwind` expects an array. `songs` is not in an array format

Comment: I modified the `songs` structure to be of array format. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change the '=>' delimiter in the document. Then you will have a JSON file

```
document = JSON.parse(document)
```

You will get a hash. Then check if likes > 50 in the hash

```
document[].each do |song|
    song[].each do |id|    
        if id[likes].to_i > 50
            #Do what you want to do
        end 
    end
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: No I asked for the `JSON` link frnd :)

Comment: This would mean doing it via ruby. And if the document is quite big, parsing through ruby would imply performance impact

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
songs_arr = [] 
document["songs"].keys.each do |key|
  songs_arr << "insert songs here"  if document["songs"][key]["likes"] > 50
end
```

Comment: This would mean doing it via ruby. And if the document is quite big, parsing through ruby would imply performance impact